# can we call a method having argument as java.lang.reflect.Array?

Tags: java, reflection

I am having doubt on below code which uses parameter as `java.lang.reflect.Array`.

```
public static void display(java.lang.reflect.Array stringArray) {
    System.out.println(java.lang.reflect.Array.get(stringArray, 1));
}
```

Above mentioned code will compile successfully but whether i should write this method and what could be the possible use-case?

if i can write such method how can we call this method however `we can not instantiate java.lang.reflect.Array` and also we can not get object from `Class` class reference as we can get `java.lang.reflect.Field` object.

Comment: What is the goal of this code? What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Actually i just got think of this code!! so i tried but i was not able to call it that is why i asked, whether it could be possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is just a helper class - note how *all* the methods on it are static. I wouldn't expect there to ever be an instance of it. To accept an array - and *any* array, including `int[]` etc - you'd need to make the method accept `Object`:

```
public static void display(Object stringArray) {
    System.out.println(java.lang.reflect.Array.get(stringArray, 1));
}
```

At that point, you can pass a `String[]` as the argument, and it will print out the second element.

However, if you *want* to only accept string arrays, why not write:

```
public static void display(String[] stringArray) {
    System.out.println(stringArray[1]);
}
```

? Now it's clear what you intend...